# PyTorch: vectorising looping addition of one value from a vector to a vector

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to create a matrix that contains every combination of the sums of all elements in two large vectors using Torch, ultimately using CUDA within Torch.

The best way to describe it is with this (inefficient) code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

x = torch.Tensor([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5])
x_cent = torch.Tensor([10.2,20.2,100.1])

res_matrix = torch.zeros([int((x.shape)[0]), int((x_cent.shape)[0])])
res_col = torch.zeros([int((x.shape)[0])])


for i in x_cent:
    res_col = x.add(i)

for i in range(0,int((x_cent.shape)[0])):
    res_col = x.add(x_cent[i])
    res_matrix[:,i] = res_col

print(res_matrix)
```

The output of this is:

```
> tensor([[ 11.3000,  21.3000, 101.2000],
        [ 12.4000,  22.4000, 102.3000],
        [ 13.5000,  23.5000, 103.4000],
        [ 14.6000,  24.6000, 104.5000],
        [ 15.7000,  25.7000, 105.6000]])
```

There may be a term for this operation, and if someone can point it out, I will edit
this question and include the term.

Can you suggest a more efficient (vectorised?) approach to this that I could implement using the CUDA device on very large vectors? I'm guessing that this is a very simple question, but I am a beginner with torch.

Thanks!

Comment: your output doesn't look like vector addition.  Also, you can't 'add' two vectors of unequal lengths. Are you trying to take the dot product of two vectors?

Comment: Yes, it is currently a looped addition of every point in one vector to every one in the other vector.  You can see from code example exactly what I want. No -- it is not a dot product. Look at the output from the calculation -- you have an n length vector and an m length vector. The output is an m X n matrix that contains every combination of sum of all values.   I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompted by a comment above, and looking around, I see that a similar blog post exists:
[every combination of addition of two vectors -- but not a matrix](https://dongkwan-kim.github.io/blogs/all-possible-combinations-of-row-wise-addition-using-pytorch/)

This can be modified to produce a matrix:

```
(x.unsqueeze(1) + x_cent.unsqueeze(0))
```

Any better approaches?